# Does $0^{\#}$ imply that $L$'s set generic multiverse has irreconcilable theories?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, inner-model-theory

Suppose $0^{\#}$ exists. Let $M(L)$ be the generic multiverse over $L$ as viewed in $V$, i.e. $M(L)$ consists of all $L[g]$ where $g \in V$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $L$ for some forcing $\mathbb{P} \in L$.

In a [previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304236/does-0-imply-the-failure-of-upward-directedness-in-the-set-generic-univer) we established that $M(L)$ is not upward directed, i.e. there are $M,N \in M(L)$ such that for all $K \in M(L) \colon M \cup N \not \subseteq K$.

Let us consider the following weakening:

**Definition 1.** $M(L)$'s pointwise theory is reconcilable iff for all $M,N \in M(L)$ there are $M',N' \in M(L)$ such that $M \subseteq M', N \subseteq N'$ and $\mathrm{Th}((M'; \in)) = \mathrm{Th}((N'; \in))$.

**Question 2.** Is $M(L)$'s pointwise theory reconcilable?

Again, there is an easy partial answer:

**Proposition 3.** Let $M_{< \omega_{1}}(L)$ be the generic universe over $L$ restricted to posets $\mathbb{P}$ such that $V \models \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{P}) < \omega_1$. $M_{< \omega_{1}}(L)$'s pointwise theory is reconcilable.

Proof. Let $\mathbb P, \mathbb Q \in L$ be such that 
$$
V \models \mathrm{card}(\mathbb{P}),\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{Q}) < \omega_1.
$$
Let $g \in V$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $L$ and let $h \in V$ be $\mathbb{Q}$-generic over $L$.
Since $\omega_1^V$ is a limit of $L$-inaccessibles, we may fix some $L$-inaccessible $\kappa < \omega_1^L$ such that $\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{J}_\kappa$. Since $\mathcal{J}_{\kappa}$ is countable in $V$, there are $g',h' \in V$ which are $\mathrm{Coll}(\omega, \kappa)$-generic over $L$ such that $L[g] \subseteq L[g']$ and $L[h] \subseteq L[h']$. Now recall that $\mathrm{Coll}(\omega, \kappa)$ is weakly homogeneous and thus $\mathrm{Th}((L[g']; \in)) = \mathrm{Th}((L[h']; \in))$. Q.E.D.

Comment: Note that the answer in the generic multiverse of $V$ is positive, i.e. if $g,h \in V[G]$ are generic filters over $L$ ($G$ is a generic filter over $V$) there is some generic filter $H$ such that in $V[H]$ there are $g',h'$ generic over $L$ such that $L[g] \subseteq L[g'], L[h] \subseteq L[h']$ and $L[g'], L[h']$ have the same theory. Just use $H$ to collapse a sufficiently large $V[G]$ cardinal to obtain generic filters for $\mathrm{Coll}(\omega, \alpha)$ for $\alpha > \mathrm{card}^{V[G]}(\mathbb{P} \cup \mathbb{Q})$. [..]

Comment: [..] As a result many natural approaches, that come to mind when trying to force irreconcilable theories, simply can't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\mathrm{Th}(M,\in)$? It seems like you want to allow parameters, but then how do you compare truths about parameters between different models?

Comment: The result is false with parameters, since we can add the non-amalgamable Cohen reals. So I think he just means the parameter-free theory. With $0^\sharp$, we have a truth predicate for $L$, so we can refer to the theory in $V$.

Comment: @MihaHabič $\mathrm{Th}(M; \in)$ is the parameter-free first order theory of $(M; \in)$.

Comment: Is it clear that if $0^\sharp$ exists then $V$ has an $L$-generic for some uncountable poset? It seems possible that only countable posets have generics and then your proposition covers all of the cases. For example, what happens in $L[0^\sharp]$?

Comment: Perhaps $V$ can build $L$-generics for $\text{Coll}(\kappa,\kappa^+)$ when $\kappa$ is indiscernible? (even uncountable) After all, $V$ can make a list of $\kappa$ many dense sets that suffice. But I don't quite see how to make it through limits in the diagonalization.

Comment: @Joel I've thought about that as well. Unfortunately $V$ and $L$ massively disagree about what $\mathrm{Coll}(\kappa, \kappa^{+})$ is... I've also thought about reflecting a possible failure via (very) large cardinals and then use something along the lines of proposition 3. But thus far I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Of course I want to use L's version.

Comment: @Miha $V$ has $L$-generics for ${\rm Col}(\omega,<\omega_1^V)$ if $0^\sharp$ exists. This has been known for a while, at least since Hjorth's thesis.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Do those arguments also show that $V$ has $L$-generics for $\text{Add}(\omega,\omega_1)$ and $\text{Add}(\omega_1,1)$?

Comment: @Joel Yes for ${\rm Add}(\omega,\omega_1)$. I would have to check about the other one

Comment: I guess that case follows directly anyway, since it is a subforcing notion of the one you mentioned previously.

Comment: @Joel: Don't you have an $L$-ultrafilter which is $\kappa$-complete assuming $0^\#$? Can't you use that to diagonalize?